# Import database from xml

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, import, db2

I am using `IBM DB2 v9.1` and want to export all database to xml file and them import it back when needed. There are 9 tables in my database.

I am using `java and hibernate`. What I have done so far is: fetch all data through hibernate and fill POJO objects, then export the objects to xml file. Now for import I need to delete all existing databases first and them import xml file data to the database.

**Problem is with primary keys** (ids). Once id is deleted from DB2 then data cannot be saved with that id and it will be assigned new id. This disturbs foreign key relation. What is the best possible solution for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After importing file all relations will be mapped to check their inter relation. New objects will be created after mapping relation and they will saved in database with new ID’s as DB2 will not save data on an old deleted ID and it saves it to a new ID.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export/import data for testing purpose you may want to consider DbUnit http://www.dbunit.org/index.html

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by all database? all data? or even the DDL?

I think you are exporting all data, and you leave the tables created to be refilled with the exported data.

The problem are the constraints and the generated values. There is a good article about generated values: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/0205pilaka/0205pilaka2.html

For the referential contraints, the best is to drop/deactivate them before import, then import data, and finally recreate/active referential constraints.

Here, a good stored procedure to enable/disable constraints: http://www.dzone.com/snippets/db2-enabledisable-constraints

Comment: Droping table might work but I have to work without dropping table.

Comment: I did not say dropping tables, I meant dropping constraints or deactivate them.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the [MERGE statement](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc%2Fdoc%2Fr0010873.htm) can come to your rescue.  If there already is a row with the matching id, it will let you update the row.  If there is no row with a matching ID, then it will let you insert it.

So then the question might become, do you really need to delete the rows from DB2 when you create the XML files?

Comment: I tried but merge did not give me results. After deletion I save that entity with merge() but it save with new ID, although ID was set to old one before calling merge().

Comment: It sounds like you may have identity fields that are defined with GENERATE ALWAYS rather than GENERATE BY DEFAULT. Can you, or your DBA alter those definitions?